# How to migrate Mysql database in production without losing data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3.1

We need to modify (such as add/remove table, add/remove/change column in current table) the mysql production database with the progress of  development of the rails 3.1 app. What's the best way to do that? There is valuable data in production database and they should be retained after the modification.

Thanks.

Comment: The app has been deployed on production server. I can run rake db:production:prepare on production server. However not sure if this will lose all current data.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you have tried but [Rails Database Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) is what you are looking for.

Comment: The app has been deployed on production server. I can run rake db:production:prepare on production server. However not sure if this will lose all current data.

Comment: I would replicate the production database locally to your dev or staging environment and than run the migrations. Run all your tests and make sure they pass. Once you are happy with the results, backup your production database and than run the migrations in production.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I believe if i understand your question is - to keep your data and schema copy handy and maintain them using some standard naming convention like dd-mm-yy-timestamp. this will allow you to take hot backup/cold backup. while in rails you can play with migrations to and from. but not keep data as well. if the data is a seed data then it can be returned and reversed.

The solution is other hand is more handy.you can write cron jobs and call shell scripts to make sure your operation is not manual and keeps the backup copy at safe location.